# Group_by and summarise and preserve initial order without arrange R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I need to preserve row order after `group_by` and `summarise`.

Here is initial dataset:

```
movmnt_id <- c("101", "101", "351", "601","601","351")
plant <- c("F5P", "F5D", "F5P", "F5D","F5D", "RUP")
loc <- c("CB00", "CB00", "CB00", "CB00","CB00","MOS1")
qty <- c(100, 100,100,10,90,88)
date <- c("2018-01-05","2018-01-05","2018-01-05","2018-01-11","2018-01-11","2018-01-22" )
time <- c("10:38:38","10:47:17", "10:47:09","17:20:31","17:20:24","12:00:54" )


df <-  data.frame(movmnt_id,  plant, loc, qty,date, time)
df

  movmnt_id  plant  loc   qty       date     time
1       101   F5P  CB00   100   2018-01-05   10:38:38
2       101   F5D  CB00   100   2018-01-05   10:47:17
3       351   F5P  CB00   100   2018-01-05   10:47:09
4       601   F5D  CB00    10   2018-01-11   17:20:31
5       601   F5D  CB00    90   2018-01-11   17:20:24
6       351   RUP  MOS1    88   2018-01-22   12:00:54
```

I need first to order according to specific conditions (here the dataset and conditions are significantly simplified). I do it like that:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  
  dplyr::group_by( movmnt_id, plant, loc,date,time) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total_qty = sum(qty)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange( date,time) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

df2

  movmnt_id plant loc   date       time     total_qty
  <fct>     <fct> <fct> <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
1 101       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05 10:38:38       100
2 351       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05 10:47:09       100
3 101       F5D   CB00  2018-01-05 10:47:17       100
4 601       F5D   CB00  2018-01-11 17:20:24        90
5 601       F5D   CB00  2018-01-11 17:20:31        10
6 351       RUP   MOS1  2018-01-22 12:00:54        88
```

This result is ok. And then I need to drop `timestamp` and `summarise` by qty.
My last attmept looks like this:

```
df3  <- df2 %>%
  dplyr::group_by( movmnt_id, plant, loc,date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total_qty = sum(total_qty)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

df3

  movmnt_id plant loc   date       total_qty
  <fct>     <fct> <fct> <fct>          <dbl>
1 101       F5D   CB00  2018-01-05       100
2 101       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05       100
3 351       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05       100
4 351       RUP   MOS1  2018-01-22        88
5 601       F5D   CB00  2018-01-11       100
```

This is not ok - I am loosing previous order.

What I need is one row for `movmnt_id = 601` and the same order as in df2, `movmnt_id = 351`with date 2018-01-05 should be between movements 101 with th same date :

```
  movmnt_id plant loc   date       time     total_qty
  <fct>     <fct> <fct> <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
1 101       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05 10:38:38       100
2 351       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05 10:47:09       100
3 101       F5D   CB00  2018-01-05 10:47:17       100
4 601       F5D   CB00  2018-01-11 17:20:24       100
5 351       RUP   MOS1  2018-01-22 12:00:54        88
```

Basically, if all values in grouping condition are the same except qty - these rows can be summed, but if not - order have to be kept.

How can I do it?

Comment: No, that's´ not enough, it will not work for all the cases. It is important to arrange first by timestamp.

Comment: Row ordering have nothing to do with the data unless you have a timeseries. Otherwise an aggregated dataset will have a non-guaranteed ordering and will still maintain the required properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain the same order from `df2` you can create a unique key and `match`.

```
cols <- c('movmnt_id', 'plant', 'loc', 'date')
df3 <- df3[order(match(do.call(paste, df3[cols]), do.call(paste, df2[cols]))), ]
df3

# movmnt_id plant loc   date       total_qty
#  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>          <dbl>
#1 101       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05       100
#2 351       F5P   CB00  2018-01-05       100
#3 101       F5D   CB00  2018-01-05       100
#4 601       F5D   CB00  2018-01-11       100
#5 351       RUP   MOS1  2018-01-22        88
```

Comment: This is nice! Thanks! Looks like working for bigger dataset as well. Could I ask you to explain a bit how it works? I cannot understand how this code impacts rows order. As I understand it it should impact columns order only.

Comment: This is reordering rows. Combining the values in `cols` in `df2` it creates a pasted string based on which the rows in `df3` are reordered. To better understand how this works I would suggest to run this step by step on smaller dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Here I make an ordered factor, here called "key", for the id / plant / loc combinations in chronological order. Then when we aggregate by it (shortcut using count in place of `group_by %>% summarize`), and count uses it to order the output.

```
library(forcats)  # alternatively, load with library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  arrange(date, time) %>%
  mutate(key = paste(movmnt_id, plant, loc) %>% as_factor %>% fct_inorder()) %>%
  count(key, date, movmnt_id, plant, loc, wt = qty, name = "total_qty")

           key       date movmnt_id plant  loc total_qty
1 101 F5P CB00 2018-01-05       101   F5P CB00       100
2 351 F5P CB00 2018-01-05       351   F5P CB00       100
3 101 F5D CB00 2018-01-05       101   F5D CB00       100
4 601 F5D CB00 2018-01-11       601   F5D CB00       100
5 351 RUP MOS1 2018-01-22       351   RUP MOS1        88
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly, you want to maintain the order given by the date variable. List `date` first in the `group_by` arguments to ensure that the `summarise` command uses `date` as primary key.

```
df %>%
  group_by(date, movmnt_id, plant, loc) %>%
  summarise(total_qty = sum(qty)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'date', 'movmnt_id', 'plant'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   date       movmnt_id plant loc   total_qty
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-05 101       F5D   CB00        100
#> 2 2018-01-05 101       F5P   CB00        100
#> 3 2018-01-05 351       F5P   CB00        100
#> 4 2018-01-11 601       F5D   CB00        100
#> 5 2018-01-22 351       RUP   MOS1         88
```

Comment: Almost, but row with `movmnt_id = 351` and `date = 2018-01-05`  changed it´s position. It has the same date as movements 101 but according to transactions history have to be between them. That is why I am arranging by time first. Dataset is much more complex and there could be a lot of repeated transactions with different qty on the same date, so it is important first to understand if they have been done one by one and then qty can be summed in one line or there were another transactions in between - in that case it have to be splitted according to the time sequence.